# NDSolve issue with summation

Tags: differential-equations, summation

I have the following equation I am trying to plot,

$r''=f(r)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^n \frac{d^n}{dt^n}(f(r))$

and $r$ is a vector in $(x,y,z)$ that are time dependent. I wrote the code as follows,

```
Clear[x, y, z, t, a];
Dmax = Infinity;
tmax = 10;
r = {x[t], y[t], z[t]};
equation =  D[r, {t, 2}] + r/ (r^2 + 2^2)^(1/2) + 
 Sum[(a^n (D[r/ (r^2 + 2^2)^(1/2),   {t, n}])),{n,Dmax};

 p = Thread[(r /. t -> 0) - {1.0, 0, 0} == 0];
 v = Thread[(D[r, t] /. t -> 0) - {0.0, 1.0, 1.0} == 0];

 Equation2 = Join[Thread[equation == 0], p, v];

 solution1 = 
 NDSolve[Equation2 /. a -> 0.0, r, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
 Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];

 solution2 = 
 NDSolve[Equation2 /. a -> 0.1, r, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
 Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];

 b1[t_] = r /. solution1;
 b2[t_] = r /. solution2;

  plot3D1 = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{b1[t][[1, 1]], b1[t][[1, 2]], b1[t][[1, 3]]}, {t, 
  0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> Cyan, DisplayFunction -> Identity, 
  PlotLegends -> {"b1"}];

  plot3D2 = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{b2[t][[1, 1]], b2[t][[1, 2]], b2[t][[1, 3]]}, {t, 
  0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dotted, Thickness -> 0.02}, 
  DisplayFunction -> Identity, PlotLegends -> {"b2"}];

  Show[plot3D1, plot3D2, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> 450, ViewPoint -> Above]

  Sum[(a^n (D[r/ (r^2 + 2^2)^(1/2), {t, n}])),{n,Dmax}
```

The issue I have is that NDSolve works for $Dmax=Infinity$ as well as for values of $2,3$, however it fails to solve for values equal and greater than $4$.  How do I fix the problem?  Why it works at infinity?

Comment: Your code doesn't run for `Dmax = Infinity`:  NDSolve gives error ` NDSolve::ndord: Derivative order K[1] in term (x^(K[1]))[t] should be a non-negative machine-sized integer.` concerning the highest derivative in the ode.

Comment: I'd recommend first getting an idea of what $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^n\frac{d^nf(\vec{r}(t))}{dt^n}$ even means [mathematically](https://math.stackexchange.com). Is there a closed-form expression for this term? If not, I'd be concerned about the numerical stability of calculating high-order numerical derivatives (as `NDSolve` does internally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete solution; merely a simplification of the OP's right-hand side to get rid of high-order derivatives and replace them by a manageable formula.

Let's define a function $g(t)=f(\vec{r}(t))$ to simplify the notation a bit. We study the function
$$
g_a(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^n\frac{d^ng(t)}{dt^n}
= g(t) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^n\frac{d^ng(t)}{dt^n}
$$
as used in the OP's differential equation, assuming $a\ge0$ in what follows. We note that $g_0(t)=\lim_{a\to0^+} g_a(t)=g(t)$.

Starting with the Fourier transform
$$
g(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega\,
\hat{g}(\omega)e^{-i \omega t}\\
\hat{g}(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt\,
g(t)e^{i \omega t}
$$
we compute
$$
g_a(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^n\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\left(
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega\,
\hat{g}(\omega)e^{-i \omega t}
\right)\\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega\,
\hat{g}(\omega)
\left(
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^n\frac{d^n}{dt^n}
e^{-i \omega t}
\right)
$$

```
Sum[a^n D[Exp[-I ω t], {t, n}], {n, 0, ∞}] // FullSimplify
(*    E^(-I ω t)/(1 + I ω a)    *)
```

$$
g_a(t)
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega\,
\hat{g}(\omega)
\left(
\frac{e^{-i \omega t}}{1+i\omega a}
\right)\\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega\,
\left(
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ds\,
g(s)e^{i \omega s}
\right)
\left(
\frac{e^{-i \omega t}}{1+i\omega a}
\right)\\
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ds\,
g(s)
\left(
\frac{1}{2\pi}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega\,
\frac{e^{-i \omega (t-s)}}{1+i\omega a}
\right)
$$
With $\delta=t-s$ we can integrate the parenthesis using [`InverseFourierTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFourierTransform.html):

```
1/Sqrt[2 π] InverseFourierTransform[1/(1 + I ω a), ω, δ, 
              Assumptions -> a > 0]
(*    E^(δ/a)*HeavisideTheta[-δ]/a    *)
```

and therefore
$$
g_a(t)
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ds\,
g(s)
\left(
\frac{e^{(t-s)/a} \theta(s-t)}{a}
\right)\\
= \int_{t}^{\infty}ds\,
\frac{g(s)e^{-(s-t)/a}}{a}\\
= \int_{0}^{\infty}d\tau\,
\frac{g(t+\tau)e^{-\tau/a}}{a}
$$
where $\tau=s-t$ was substituted.
We see that the right-hand side of the OP's differential equation can be written as an exponentially decreasing average: the function $g_a(t)$ is an average of all $g(s)$ for $s\ge t$ with a weight that decreases exponentially as $s\to\infty$; the exponential decrease happens on a time-scale $a$. This exponential average is much easier to evaluate in practice than a sum over derivatives of very high order, especially when numerical data are involved (i.e. when $g(t)$ is known by numerical sampling).

The original differential equation is now
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2} \vec{r}(t) = g_a(t)
= \int_{0}^{\infty}d\tau\,
\frac{e^{-\tau/a}}{a}f(\vec{r}(t+\tau)).
$$
Solving this integro-differential equation is step 2 that would make this solution usable.

Comment: It is a very interesting approach that you are proposing and its very unique.  I never though about this method that way.   I will definately look at it and see how to adapt it to my problem.